# pytest not allowing classes with non-static methods

Tags: python, unit-testing, oop, static-methods, pytest

I was following this tutorial for pytest:

http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#grouping-multiple-tests-in-a-class

But noticed that if I create:

```
class ComplexTestClass:
    """
    Complex and more nuanced tests for specific sentences
    """
    def test_multiple_sentences():
```

If I do not add  `@staticmethod` at the top of the functions, I get an error appearing on the function where it cannot pick up with `()` is and it gets highlighted in red in my PyCharm.

Is the tutorial (which shows no need for static methods) wrong, or am I wrong and will `staticmethod` invalidate my tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `self` argument in the method if you're not declaring it a `@staticmethod`:

```
def test_multiple_sentences(self):
```

Comment: per the `pytest` docs, why does it have the example it has without `self` and without `_init_`? My objective is to have that class called within `pytest` and all its methods when I run my tests. Will `staticmethod` prevent that when I run `pytest -q test_text.py`?

Comment: The exact example you link to *does* have `self` as an argument.  The examples on that page without a `self` argument are functions defined outside a `class`, not methods.  Follow the example you linked to (i.e. don't declare your test methods as `@staticmethod`s and include the `self` argument) and all of your test cases should run.